# Does a larger laptop screen size reduce graphics performance?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, display, graphics, vram

For example, does a laptop with a 17" screen have lesser graphics performance than the same graphics card in a laptop with a 15.6" screen?

The common sense answer would be "yes", but in the computer world, I understand not everything is common sense.

(Like for example, that a faster rotational speed for a hdd does not necessarily mean your hard drive will be faster; if it has a higher latency, it might even be slower. That is not common sense if you didn't know about latency. So that is why I am asking - maybe there is a variable you know that I don't, and that you could tell me. I am open-minded).

Answer (score 7):

Screen size has nothing to do with video performance.

Resolution does: the higher resolution, the slower (which is logical since you have to calculate/draw more pixels).

Of course, bigger screens usually allow higher resolutions.

Answer (score 5):

it depends more on the pixel dimensions of the screen (rather than their physical size) as you get *the same performance with both at the same pixel dimensions*. and it's common to find higher pixel density on the physically smaller screens than the physically larger ones.

so shortly, maybe not, it might not be slower if the 17in screen has the same number of pixels as the 15.6in screen.

(and about harddisks in your example: the seek time is directly related to the rotational speed (lower seek time : higher rotational speed) but not so directly related to the read and write speed)